# Adding item to basket link in php

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I am trying to insert a a href into php to add the items to the basket. but it is giving me the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'file_id' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in mproducts.php on line 96

Here is my code:

```
echo '<a href="mproducts.php?page=mproducts&action=add&id<?php echo $row['file_id']?>">Add to Basket</a>';
```

Comment: Here `<?php echo $row['file_id']?>` you are already in PHP. Just concatenate.

Comment: The `&id` should also have an `=`.

Comment: Like this: echo '<a href="mproducts.php?page=mproducts&action=add&id">Add to Basket</a>' . <?php echo $row['file_id']?>;

Comment: @chris85 still giving me an error

Comment: You shouldn't have `<?php` inside of `<?php`. Once you are in PHP use PHP functions/syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things, you don't use PHP tags inside PHP statements, and you join (or "concatenate") echo statements with either periods or commas.

Like this...

```
echo '<a href="mproducts.php?page=mproducts&action=add&id=', $row['file_id'], '">Add to Basket</a>';
```

Or...

```
echo '<a href="mproducts.php?page=mproducts&action=add&id=' . $row['file_id'] . '">Add to Basket</a>';
```

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thank you very much

Comment: Note the commas aren't concatenating, that is outputting each part. If commas are used outside of `echo` for concatenating that will fail.

Comment: @chris85 Yes. Technically using commas with `echo` isn't called "concatenation", but it is does accomplish the same thing and is slightly faster. And yes, `echo` is also about the only place where commas are used in this manner.